# Error on substring function when inside a loop

Tags: java, replace, substring

I'm trying to find out if the input of the user is decimal or fraction or mixed fraction and when there is a decimal with fraction I would like to replace the decimal to a whole number so that it would be a proper mixed fraction
for example:
input: 2.23 1/2 
expected output: 2 1/2

```
public class DecimalOrFraction {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String partOfString;
        String[] s = { "0000.2","2","2.222 1/2","1 2/2", "0"};
        for (int x = 0 ;x<s.length;x++) {
            if(s[x].matches("[1-9]{1}\\d{0,3}([.]\\d{1,3}\\s{0,1})?")){
                System.out.println(x+") "+Float.valueOf(s[x])+"  ----   Decimal");
            }
            else if(s[x].matches("[1-9]{1,5}([.]\\d{1,3})?\\s[1-9]{1}\\d{0,2}([/]\\d{0,3})?")){
                partOfString = s[x].substring( s[x].lastIndexOf("."), s[x].lastIndexOf(" ")); //HAVING AN ERROR
                s[x] = s[x].replace(partOfString," "); 
                System.out.println(x+") "+s[x]+"  ----  Fraction");
            }
            else if(s[x].matches("[1-9]\\d{0,4}[/]\\d{0,3}")){
                System.out.println(x+") "+s[x]+"  ----  also Fraction");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(x+") "+s[x]+"  ----  ERROR/Zero");   
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

Is there another way to make this work without any error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because there is no dot in "1 2/2" to take the index of.
Since the matching uses RegEx, why not use RegEx for the replacement as well?
Here's a pass at refactoring the whole thing.

```
private static final Pattern DECIMAL = Pattern.compile("\\d*\\.?\\d+");
private static final Pattern FRACTION = Pattern.compile("\\.\\d+(\\s+\\d+/\\d+)");

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] samples = {"0000.2", "2", "2.222 1/2", "1 2/2", "0"};

    for (String sample : samples) {
        if (DECIMAL.matcher(sample).matches()) {
            float decimal = Float.parseFloat(sample);
            System.out.println(decimal + (decimal == 0 ? "\tERROR/Zero" : "\tDecimal"));
        }
        else {
            String fraction = FRACTION.matcher(sample).replaceFirst("$1");
            System.out.println(fraction + "\tFraction");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can ONLY have at most two separate parts then you can use String.split() and split on a " " white space. Then if you have two parts it's easier to work with. If you have one, again, simple conditionals. I don't think there's a need for this much messy regex.

Alterantively, if you have more than one whitespace, simply call each resulting split string against a regex for either of your two cases and handle that way.

Comment: String s = "0.2345 1/2";
String[] splitString = s.split(" ");